# Oracle (ORA-02270) : Have tried following other answers but can not figure it out

Tags: sql, oracle

Complete beginner here. I have been trying to mess around with this code and I stripped it back to this:

```
create table Customer
(
  Customer_Num varchar2(7) not null,
  Surname       varchar2(50) not null,
  Other_Names   varchar2(100) not null,
  Email         varchar2(320) not null,  
  Mobile_Phone  varchar2(20) not null,

  constraint Customer_PK primary key (Customer_Num)
);

create table Store
(
  Store_ID     varchar2(5) not null,
  Region      varchar2(50) not null,


  constraint Store_PK primary key (Store_ID)

);


create table Sale
(
  Store_ID       varchar2(5) not null,
  Recorded_On timestamp not null,
  Customer_Num varchar2(7) not null,
  Comments      varchar2(4000), 

  constraint Product_PK primary key (Store_ID, Recorded_On),
  constraint Sale_Store_FK foreign key (Store_ID) references Store(Store_ID),
  constraint Sale_Customer_FK foreign key (Customer_Num) references Customer(Customer_Num)
);

create table Product
(
  Store_ID varchar2(5) not null,
  Recorded_On timestamp not null,
  Product_Name varchar2(50),
  Value varchar2(50),

  constraint Product_PK primary key(Value),
  constraint Product_FK foreign key(Store_ID) references Store(Store_ID),
  constraint Product_FK foreign key(Recorded_On) references Sale(Recorded_On)

);
```

```
Error starting at line : 67 in command -
create table Product
(
  Store_ID varchar2(5) not null,
  Recorded_On timestamp not null,
  Product_Name varchar2(50),
  Value varchar2(50),

  constraint Product_PK primary key(Value),
  constraint Product_FK foreign key(Store_ID) references Store,
  constraint Product_FK foreign key(Recorded_On) references Sale(Recorded_On)

)
```

Error report -

```
SQL Error: ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list
02270. 00000 -  "no matching unique or primary key for this column-list"
*Cause:    A REFERENCES clause in a CREATE/ALTER TABLE statement
           gives a column-list for which there is no matching unique or primary
           key constraint in the referenced table.
*Action:   Find the correct column names using the ALL_CONS_COLUMNS
           catalog view
```

Thanks in advance!

- UPDATE *

I have changed code as follows

```
create table Customer
(
  Customer_Num varchar2(7) not null,
  Surname       varchar2(50) not null,
  Other_Names   varchar2(100) not null,
  Email         varchar2(320) not null,
  Mobile_Phone  varchar2(20) not null,

  constraint Customer_PK primary key (Customer_Num)
);

create table Store
(
  Store_ID     varchar2(5) not null,
  Region      varchar2(50) not null,


  constraint Store_PK primary key (Store_ID)

);


create table Sale
(
  Store_ID       varchar2(5) not null,
  Recorded_On timestamp not null UNIQUE,
  Customer_Num varchar2(7) not null,
  Comments      varchar2(4000), 

  constraint Sale_PK primary key (Store_ID, Recorded_On),
  constraint Sale_Store_FK foreign key (Store_ID) references Store(Store_ID),
  constraint Sale_Customer_FK foreign key (Customer_Num) references Customer
);

create table Product
(
  Store_ID varchar2(5) not null,
  Recorded_On timestamp not null,
  Product_Name varchar2(50),
  Value varchar2(50),

  constraint Product_PK primary key(Store_ID, Recorded_On),
  constraint Product_Store_FK foreign key(Store_ID) references Store,
  constraint Product_recorded_FK foreign key(Recorded_On) references Sale(Recorded_On)

);
```

Now I run into this error when inserting statement:

```
INSERT INTO Product (Store_ID, Recorded_On, Product_Name, Value) VALUES ('AB1', to_date('10/05/2016 13:11', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'Test', 2.0);
```

```
Error starting at line : 80 in command -
INSERT INTO Product (Store_ID, Recorded_On, Product_Name, Value) VALUES ('AB1', to_date('10/05/2016 13:11', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'Test', 2.0)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (Hemi89.PRODUCT_RECORDED_FK) violated - parent key not found
02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"
*Cause:    A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
*Action:   Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.
```

I am little confused here as I believe I have set parent key in constraint Sale_PK primary key (Store_ID, Recorded_On) in the Sales Table.

Comment: For which Statement you get this error?

Comment: Error starting at line : 67 in command -
create table Product
(
  Store_ID varchar2(5) not null,
  Recorded_On timestamp not null,
  Product_Name varchar2(50),
  Value varchar2(50),
  
  constraint Product_PK primary key(Value),
  constraint Product_FK foreign key(Store_ID) references Store,
  constraint Product_FK foreign key(Recorded_On) references Sale(Recorded_On)
 
)

Comment: As the error message *no matching unique or primary key for this column-list* says. The referenced column must have a unique constraint or must be a Primary key, which is not the case for column `Recorded_On`

Comment: You can't call two primary keys `Product_PK`.  You can't call two foreign keys `Product_FK`.  You can't have a foreign key reference to `Sale(Recorded_On)` because `Sale(Recorded_On)` isn't unique or a primary key.

Answer (score 3):

The foreign key you're trying to create on Recorded_On column in product table must refer to a primary key or an unique key. Recorded_On column in your Sale table must be changed to unique or don't create any constraints on it.

After you resolve this error, the next problem you'll run into is constraints not having unique names.

```
ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint
```

Constraint Name Product_PK & Product_FK gets repeated twice.

Comment: Thanks, Now I have trouble inserting statement:

INSERT INTO Product (Store_ID, Recorded_On, Product_Name, Value) VALUES ('AB1', to_date('10/05/2016 13:11', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'Test', 2.0);
Error starting at line : 80 in command -
INSERT INTO Product (Store_ID, Recorded_On, Product_Name, Value) VALUES ('AB1', to_date('10/05/2016 13:11', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 'Test', 2.0)
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-02291: integrity constraint (Hemi89.PRODUCT_RECORDED_FK) violated - parent key not found
02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"